# How do I notify my iPhone app via php that a name has been added to a database or not?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, objective-c

My iPhone app communicates through a php file with my mySql database. Everything works fine. But when I send the form and the username already exists, the php file should somehow backfire a notification. What should I do ?

**php File**

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM userData WHERE username = '$username'";  
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    // WHAT SHOULD BE DONE HERE TO NOTIFY iPHONE ? 
    }
```

I could think of a way, but it I think there is a better and more efficient way to do it.

**[EDIT]**

This is what I did to get the response:

```
 NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&error];      

         NSDictionary *jsonDictionaryResponse =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"json response = %@", jsonDictionaryResponse);
```

**[/EDIT]**

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the scenario. The iOS app sends data to the server, which tries to put it into a database, and you want to know how the server should ***respond*** to an invalid request?

Comment: No, my app sends data to a php file. This php file tries to add the username and when unsuccessful it should return something back to the app. Or at least the app should somehow know that the username already exists in the database... How would I do that ?

Comment: Well, exactly what I said. The app sends an HTTP requests (?) to your server, your server does something and returns a response. You want to return a response that says the action could not be completed. How are you currently sending the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He does not really need a push notification. Just need a response back from the server.

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM userData WHERE username = '$username'";  
$result = mysql_query($query);  
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
// WHAT SHOULD BE DONE HERE TO NOTIFY iPHONE ? 
sendResponse(200, json_encode('SUCCESS Notification'));
}
```

Where sendResponse looks like this

// Helper method to send a HTTP response code/message

```
function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html')
{
    $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . 'OK';
    header($status_header);
    header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
    echo $body;
}
```

Comment: Ok this is exactly what I am looking for, thank you. Do you know what my app should look do ?

Comment: Dont understand your question... "app should look do .." meaning?

Comment: Oh sorry, messed something up right there. I meant "what the app should do" mixed with "my app should look out for". I don't know how to handle the response in my app. I posted some code into my question with which I tried to get the response, but unfortunately left me unsuccessful. I would appreciate it if you looked it through.

Comment: I guess if it is the success notification you continue with your normal flow. Else show an error in your app..or whatever is the flow in your app